# Determinant as a sum of determinants of submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

I have seen once a formula for calculating the determinant of a block matrix which was something like this. Suppose $M$ is a matrix given by:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\
-B & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ ($n$ even) positive matrices such that $\det M \neq 0$. For $I,J \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$, $A_{I\times J} = (a_{ij})_{i\in I, j\in J}$ is the restriction of the matrix $A$ with respect to the sets $I,J$. If my memory serves me right, the formula I mentioned was something like:
$$\det M_{K \times K} = \sum_{I, J \subseteq K}\det A_{I\times J}\det B_{K\setminus I \times K\setminus J}$$
Maybe the above formula has some sign errors, but I would like to know if this formula (or some variant of it, where the determinant of $M$ reduces to the sum of determinants of submatrices indexed by partitions of $K$) exists indeed and how to prove it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $\det M=\pm \det A \det B$ can you explain what you are trying to do? And btw your proposed formula won't work in case, e.g. that $n=1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician your comments helped me to edit the question properly. First, I forgot to say that $n$ should be even. Then, I am actually trying to calculate the determinant of submatrices of $M$, as the question now clarifies.

Comment: I am still perplexed because I can't see where you define $K$. Is it just a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$? But then $I$ as a row-subscript for $A$ wouldn't work?

Comment: Now, $K$ is an arbitrary subset of $\{1,...,2n\}$, as $I,J$.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this can be got from $(XY)^{(k)}=X^{(k)}Y^{(k)}$ with $X=\begin{pmatrix} A & O\\O&B\end{pmatrix}$, $Y=\begin{pmatrix} O & I \\-I&O\end{pmatrix}$. (Matrices of $k$-minors) The second term giving the sign.